# dmesg + how to enable dmesg history logs

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, syslog, logrotate

We have RHEL server version 7.2 and we noticed that `dmesg` files from previous sessions under `/var/log` are not created

what we have under `/var/log` are only

```
ls -ltr | grep dmesg

-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    123011 Jan  3 04:03 dmesg
```

instead to get like:

```
    -rw-r--r--  1 root   root    123011 Jan  3 04:03 dmesg.0
    -rw-r--r--  1 root   root    123011 Jan  2 04:03 dmesg.1
    -rw-r--r--  1 root   root    123011 Jan  1 04:03 dmesg.2
.
.
.
```

what is the configuration that enable to save the old kernel messaged in backup files?

Comment: I just started a bounty on this, as I have the same question. I have a laptop system that is not waking after suspend and would very much like to be able to review the dmesg log from the previous session. I am personally using Parabola (Arch variant).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether the solution below solves your problem, because it seems too easy (given your rep). But here we go:

If you have `Storage=auto` in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` (which is the default in most installations I have seen), you just should create the directory `/var/log/journal`. With that setting, `systemd-journald` stores the logs in that directory if it exists, but stores the logs only in memory if it doesn't (and of course forgets them when shutting down). After having created the directory, you should execute `systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix /var/log/journal` and restart `systemd-journald`.

Probably you can configure `systemd-journald` to use another location for the log files, but this is beyond my (current) knowledge (I never needed to do so and thus didn't research the necessary steps).

If you have `Storage=persistent` in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`, `/var/log/journal` should be created automatically if needed.

For the sake of completeness, `Storage=volatile` means that the log data will only be stored in memory (and will be forgotten when shutting down), and `Storage=none` prevents any storage at all. You'll have to avoid these two if you want to see the logs from previous boots.

All of these setting are explained nicely in `man journald.conf`.

Please note that the solution outlined above relates to `systemd`, and thus is appropriate for the OP, because RHEL 7.2 is based on `systemd`.

If you insist in having a backup of old boot logs (although you already can view them using the standard configuration), you could simply issue `journalctl -b <N> > demsg.<N>`, e.g. `journalctl -b 1 > dmesg.1` to save the oldest recorded boot log into file `dmesg.1`.

Therefore, the answer to your question (*what is the configuration that enable to save the old kernel messaged in backup files*) is:

- I am not aware of any configuration setting to do that based on the `dmesg` files.
- Of course, you can write a script to rotate the `dmesg` files, and let it run after each startup or before each shutdown.
- But you can achieve your goal in a better (easier) way by following the procedure I have outlined above.

Unfortunately, the solution is not appropriate for the person who spent the bounty: It won't work with OpenRC because OpenRC isn't based on `systemd` (if I got the bounty statement right). In OpenRC, there may be other methods to solve the problem, but since I have never heard of it, I can't help there.

**Reference:**

https://gist.github.com/JPvRiel/b7c185833da32631fa6ce65b40836887

Comment: Ok, so you think dmesg log rotation can't be done in OpenRC at all, because it relies on systemd-journald (and OpenRC has no equivalent)?

Comment: No, that's not what I wanted to say. I just wanted to point out that *the solution I have shown* won't work with OpenRC, because that solution is based on `systemd`. I really do not know anything about OpenRC, so I can't tell whether there are other methods to achieve what you want. Perhaps you could configure logrotate to rotate `dmesg` after startup, or you could write your own script which does this, and put it in some file which gets executed when the multiuser runlevel is reached, or ... but I really don't know. My knowledge is restricted to Debian which I use on several machines.

Comment: so I looked at this on another system I have that is using systemd. The `/var/log/journal` folder was already present; however, there don't seem to be any dmesg files at all, either in `/var/log` or in the journal folder. I also tried setting `Storage=auto` in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`, but it didn't seem to help either. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: `systemd-journald` places the logs in a subdirectory of `/var/log/journal`. The subdirectory and the log files in it have long, cryptic names (sort of GUIDs). The log files are in binary format and thus are not appropriate for direct reading, e.g. in a text editor. Instead, you read them via `journalctl`: `journalctl -b <N>`, where `N` is the number of the boot process you want to investigate. Basically, `1` shows the first boot process recorded, `2` the second and so on. Negative numbers have other effects. For details, see `man journalctl`.

Comment: And if there are no log files at all in `/var/log/journal`, you may have to set `Storage=persistent` in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`. For details, see `man journald.conf` where the different possible values for the `Storage` stanza are explained quite at the beginning.

Comment: Please see my reworked answer.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, but tbh I'm not sure if it truly answers the original question. The OP mentions several different versions of the `dmesg` file stored in `/var/log`, not buried in the `/var/log/journal` folder structure. So, I wonder if in their case the rotation was being performed by a different tool to journald?

Comment: The OP has a rep of about 10000, so I assumed that my (originally indirect) answer was enough: I have shown why the "old" `dmesg` files are not stored, and have shown how to get hold of "old" boot logs without using those files. I further have mentioned that he could write a script which rotates his `dmesg` file after every startup if he insists. I personally would "backup" those old logs simply by `journalctl -b <N> > dmesg.<N>`, though. I believe that this is an appropriate answer, and will probably add that sentence. Plus, I now know that RHEL 7.2 uses `systemd`.

Comment: I have reworked my answer again.

Comment: Ok thanks, I appreciate your efforts and I will give you the bounty, as you are the only person who has shown any interest in answering this question. It seems the simple answer to how to rotate the `dmesg` logs would be to use a custom script or logrotate (which could be done with OpenRC), but your answer shows how it can be done in a better way in systemd with journald. Thanks again!